# Passing constructor arguments when using StructureMap

Tags: dependency-injection, constructor, structuremap

I'm using StructureMap for my DI. Imagine I have a class that takes 1 argument like:

```
public class ProductProvider : IProductProvider
{
     public ProductProvider(string connectionString)
     { 
         ....
     }
}
```

I need to specify the "connectionString **at run-time** when I get an instance of IProductProvider.

I have configured StructureMap as follows:

```
ForRequestedType<IProductProvider>.TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<ProductProvider>().  
WithCtorArgument("connectionString");
```

However, I don't want to call EqualTo("something...") method here as I need some facility to dynamically specify this value at run-time.

My question is: how can I get an instance of IProductProvider by using ObjectFactory?

Currently, I have something like:

```
ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IProductProvider>();
```

But as you know, this doesn't work...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found the answer myself! Here is the solution:

```
ObjectFactory.With("connectionString").EqualTo(someValueAtRunTime).GetInstance<IProductProvider>();
```

Hope this helps others who have come across the same issue.

Comment: Make sure that someValueAtRuntime is a simple value, not any kind of Func or Lambda (if you can do that) for retrieving it, otherwise that function will run every time the dependency is resolved. I used this trick to inject a connection string, just as you're doing. As long as you get the string into a local variable before setting up ObjectFactory, you should be fine.

Comment: Yo. What if I have several arguments, arg1, 2, 3 etc. And I want to pass in every argument as is but keep one of the args as null. How to do this?

Comment: @Mosh thank you for the answer, how ever can you please tell me how are you passing someValueAtRuneTime? an example of it please.

Answer (score 63):

I suggest declaring that with the StructureMap configuration.  Using the slightly newer StructureMap code:

```
For<IProductProvider>().Use<ProductProvider>
  .Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is(someValueAtRunTime);
```

This way you don't burden your client code from having to know the value and can keep your IoC configuration separate from your main code.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the place were you configure StructureMap. How do You pass the `someValueAtRunTime` there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running structuremap 2.6.x you will have to do the following:

```
For<IProductProvider>().Use<ProductProvider>().WithProperty("name").EqualTo(someValueAtRunTime);
```

Ensure the property name matches the constructor argument.

If your parameter is coming from the app settings use the following line:

```
.WithProperty("").EqualToAppSetting("")
```