# How to configure StructureMap to take multiple contstructor parameters?

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have the following type which I need to be instantiated by StructureMap:

```
public class AWebService : IAWebService
{
    private readonly string _applicationId;
    private readonly string _username;
    private readonly string _password;

    public AWebService(string applicationId, string username, string password)
    {
        _applicationId = applicationId;
        _username = username;
        _password = password;
    }
}
```

The problem is that this constructor takes 3 parameters. I've seen examples how to provide StructureMap with *one* parameter (e.g. [Passing constructor arguments when using StructureMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824088/passing-constructor-arguments-when-using-structuremap)) but I'm not sure what I need to do to pass 3 in.

Is it simply a case of:

```
For<IAWebService>().Use<AWebService>()
  .Ctor<string>("applicationId").Is(GetIDFromConfig())
  .Ctor<string>("username").Is(GetUsernameFromConfig())
  .Ctor<string>("password").Is(GetPasswordFromConfig());
```

or do I have to configure it differently?

Comment: have you tried that?  Seems a reasonable approach to me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried the code in your question, it looks correct.

Register your type with structuremap and set the string constructor parameters

```
var container = new Container(x => {
            x.For<IAWebService>().Use<AWebService>()
                .Ctor<string>("applicationId").Is("my app id")
                .Ctor<string>("username").Is("my username")
                .Ctor<string>("password").Is("my passowrd");
        });
```

Then you can get your service with the parameters set.

```
var service = container.GetInstance<IAWebService>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say you inject a reference of type `IConfigurationHelper` or something which holds these 3 properties. This way you can just use different types all derived from `IConfigurationHelper`