# StructureMap select multiple constructor on GenericRepository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, structuremap

I'm using GenericRepository pattern from https://github.com/huyrua/efprs. I just want to select constructor with DbContext as parameter. I know there's duplicate question, but solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924815/how-to-configure-structuremap-to-take-multiple-contstructor-parameters) didn't solve. Here's my configuration:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.Scan(scan =>
    {
        scan.TheCallingAssembly();
        scan.AssemblyContainingType<Data.Entity.TokoContainer>();
        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
    });
    x.For<DbContext>().Use<Data.Entity.TokoContainer>();
    x.For<Infrastructure.Data.IRepository>()
     .Use<Infrastructure.Data.GenericRepository>()
     .Ctor<DbContext>().Is(c => c.GetInstance<DbContext>());
});
```

this cause error "StructureMap Exception Code:  There is no argument of type System.Data.Entity.DbContext for concrete type Infrastructure.Data.GenericRepository".

When using this:

```
x.SelectConstructor<Infrastructure.Data.IRepository>(() => new Infrastructure.Data.GenericRepository((DbContext)null));
x.ForConcreteType<Infrastructure.Data.IRepository>()
 .Configure.Ctor<DbContext>().Is(c => c.GetInstance<DbContext>());
```

Causing "StructureMap configuration failures: Error 104".

Specifying from first code, adding parameter name "context" like this:

```
x.For<Infrastructure.Data.IRepository>()
 .Use<Infrastructure.Data.GenericRepository>()
 .Ctor<DbContext>("context").Is(c => c.GetInstance<DbContext>());
```

causing error "Missing requested Instance property "connectionStringName" for InstanceKey xxx". I don't know what to do now.

Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: "There is no argument of type System.Data.Entity.DbContext for concrete type Infrastructure.Data.GenericRepository". That's because the `GenericRepository` depends on `ObjectContext`. Not `DbContext`.

Comment: I am using the same library and having same exception. no wonder

Answer (score 0):

The `StructureMap` is trying to express, that the `DbContext` has *constructor* with a string parameter "connectionStringName". As you can see in the test scenario of the link you've appended: [MyDbContext.cs](https://github.com/huyrua/efprs/blob/master/net45/Infrastructure.Tests/Data/MyDbContext.cs)

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
   ...    
   public MyDbContext(string connStringName) :
      base(connStringName)
   {
     ...
```

So, what we need to do, is correctly map the constructor of the `DbContext`. For example:

```
x.For<DbContext>()
 .Use<Data.Entity.TokoContainer>()
 // example, taking the first conn string - adjust as needed
 .Ctor<string>().Is(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);
;
```

Now, even the DbContext would be correctly set

Comment: Error: StructureMap Exception Code:  302. There is no argument of type System.String for concrete type Toko.Data.Entity.TokoContainer

Comment: If TokoContainer is your class, change its constructor. You have to pass the conn string to the base DBContext anyway